# Workflow for applying Schema Changes to production using EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to define a workflow for applying schema changes to my hosted application.  Up until now I've just done `update-database` directly without any `add-migration`s.  I'd like to robustify this a bit due to my last migration unexpectedly deleting all rows from a table, here's what I'm thinking:

1. Copy DB down from Azure
2. **Make sure** connection string is pointed to local copy
3. add-migration in application, see file get generated
4. update-database -verbose
5. Test locally, inspect tables, make sure everything is OK
6. Turn the app into readonly mode
7. update connection string to point at hosted database
8. Run update-database
9. After some initial smoke tests, re-enable database
10. After significant testing, delete generated migration file to clean up VS

Does this look pretty typical?  What can I do to make this more robust / streamlined?